# prove that $x^6=(ax)^3$ implies $x^3=e,\: \forall x\in G$

Tags: group-theory

Let be $(G,\cdot)$ a group and $e$ the identity element.
Let be $a\in G$.

If $$x^6=(ax)^3,\:\forall x\in G$$
Then
$$x^3=e,\: \forall x\in G$$
What I did:

$$x^6=(ax)^3,\:\forall x\in G$$
$x \gets a^2$ then $a^3=e$.

$$x^6=(ax)^3,\:\forall x\in G \implies x^6=(xa)^3,\:\forall x\in G$$
so
$$(ax)^3=(xa)^3,\:\forall x\in G$$
How should I continue from here?

Comment: By looking at $x^{24}$ I got $x^{24}=x^3$  ....

Comment: This seems awfully similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187884/104041), including the idiosyncratic "let be" and the use of $\forall$ after the equations.

Comment: How did you get to the last step?

Answer (score 1):

As @ancient mathematician hinted, for all $x\in G$

$$x^{24} = \left(x^6\right)^4 = (ax)^{12} = \dots = x^3\,,$$

so $x^{21}=e$.

What's more, since you proved $(ax)^3 = (xa)^3$, it follows that
$$x^3 = (a^{-1}xa)^3 = a^{-1}x^3a\,,$$

which implies that $\forall x\in G, x^3a = ax^3$.

Thus $x^{18}=(x^3)^6 = a^3x^9 = x^9$, so $x^9=e$.

Finally $e=x^{21}=x^3$ since $9+9+3=21$.

Comment: Could you explain $$x^{24} = \left(x^6\right)^4 = (ax)^{12} = \dots = x^3$$

Comment: I get $$x^{24}=(x^6)^4=((ax)^3)^4=(ax)^{12}=((ax)^6)^2=((a^2x)^3)^2=(a^2 x)^6=a^3x$$

Comment: OP showed that $a^3=e$

Comment: @miracle173 Also be careful that your last equality should be $(a^2x)^6 = (a^3x)^3$

Comment: Thank you. It would be fine if you would write a self contained answer. Because not the OP's post does not contain a prove for all claims.